# d3v4 Zoomable Treemap - how to avoid overlay of child rects?

Tags: d3.js, layout, treemap

Can anyone advise on how to remove the 'overlay' aspect of the treemap layout in Martin Meier's 'Zoomable Treemap v4 (overlay)'?
https://bl.ocks.org/me1er/c64479f1ac8a5f993027f40a36c35dd9

Pen I created from Martin's code: https://codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/bLpbgZ

I assume Martin's treemap was based on Mike Bostock's (d3v3) Zoomable Treemap @ https://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap

I'd like to use aspects of the d3v4 version as a basis for a d3v4 treemap that I'm working on. I'll be doing various changes including to handle multiple measures, so I can extend the custom accumulate(), for example.

However, I'm stumped on how to modify Martin's treemap to do non-overlaying layout of the child rectangles, like Mike's original zoomable treemap.

Note that my pen is modified to use standard d3 flare api data to enable direct comparison of the layout between these two treemap implementations.

---

Relevant extracts from Mike B's d3v3 code:

```
var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
.children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })
.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
.ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
.round(false);

### snip ###

initialize(root);
accumulate(root);
layout(root);
display(root);

function initialize(root) {
   root.x = root.y = 0;
   root.dx = width;
   root.dy = height;
   root.depth = 0;
}

// Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
// treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
// We also take a snapshot of the original children (_children) to avoid
// the children being overwritten when when layout is computed.
function accumulate(d) {
    return (d._children = d.children)
    ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
    : d.value;
}

// Compute the treemap layout recursively such that each group of siblings
// uses the same size (1×1) rather than the dimensions of the parent cell.
// This optimizes the layout for the current zoom state. Note that a wrapper
// object is created for the parent node for each group of siblings so that
// the parent’s dimensions are not discarded as we recurse. Since each group
// of sibling was laid out in 1×1, we must rescale to fit using absolute
// coordinates. This lets us use a viewport to zoom.
function layout(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        treemap.nodes({_children: d._children});
        d._children.forEach(function(c) {
            c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
            c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
            c.dx *= d.dx;
            c.dy *= d.dy;
            c.parent = d;
            layout(c);
      });
  }
}
```

---

Relevant difference extracts from Martin's d3v4 code:

```
treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .round(false)
    .paddingInner(1);
}

var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
    .eachBefore(function(d) { d.id = (d.parent ? d.parent.id + "." : "") + d.data.shortName; })
    .sum((d) => d.size)
    .sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value; });

initialize(root);
accumulate(root);
layout(root);
treemap(root);
display(root);

function layout(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d._children.forEach(function(c) {
        c.x0 = d.x0 + c.x0 * d.x1;
        c.y0 = d.y0 + c.y0 * d.y1;
        c.x1 *= d.x1;
        c.y1 *= d.y1;
        c.parent = d;
        layout(c);
});
```

Thanks very much

Comment: From your question, it's difficult for me to tell what you mean by overlay, also in general it's better if you include the relevant code and area you're having difficulty with instead of links.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I edited the original posting to add relevent portions of code.

In Mike B's treemap, child rects are always laid out adjacent to each other and never overlap each other. This is what I'd like to achieve with the d3v4 version of the code.

In contrast, with Mike M's treemap, you can see the overlapping child rects due to the opacity:
https://bl.ocks.org/sshermz/0bbf39d08db29dd1bc6200d532567267

I gather that this behavior is deliberate per the 'overlay' in the description of his version of the treemap implementation.

Comment: I created a pen: https://codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/bLpbgZ

It's modified with standard D3 flare api data (added 'data2' and changed  line 1490 to 'var root = d3.hierarchy(data2);'

That makes it easier to compare the layout with Mike Bostock's original (d3v3) zoomable treemap https://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the layout of Mike M's (d3v4) treemap to be the same as Mike B's treemap.

Comment: Correction: Whereever I mentioned "Mike M", I meant "Martin M"!

Comment: The text labeling is still funky, but I figured out 90% of the layout issue myself.   

Maybe it was deliberate, but the porting of Mike's v3's x/dx, y/dy layout coordinates was not done in an equivalent manner to v4's x0/x1, y0/y1 coordinates in Martin's treemap.   

New pen: https://codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/LQNYrv

Comment: I think that the last thing remaining to make the layout identical to Mike's v3 treemap has to do with the layout ratio. Anyone know how to apply this v3 treemap.ratio code to this v4 code?  
  
https://codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/LQNYrv  

treemap.ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))

Comment: I tried d3.treemap().tile(d3.treemapResquarify.ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5))));  Looks nice, but still doesn't replicate Mike's layout. So I'm still trying to solve this last difference in the layout behaviors between these two treemaps.

Comment: `.children'enter code here'(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })` is problematic, you need to remove that 'enter code here' bit

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. I fixed it above. In any case, that was an extract of Mike Bostock's original d3v3 code, which works perfectly, and who's layout I'm trying to emulate. Per my progress which I've described in my comments, it's mostly working now except that I still prefer Mike's style of layout. Note how his first 'vis' child rect is the full width of the chart. But in my latest d3v4 version (https://codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/LQNYrv), the first 'vis' child rect's width is approx 31% of the chart's width.

Comment: FYI - Now the text postioning problems are fixed. https://codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/LQNYrv. Lastly, I'm still wondering how to replicate Mike's child rect layout. Again, note how his first 'vis' child rect (operator) is the full width of the chart. But in my 'non-overlay' d3v4 pen (codepen.io/meerkat00/pen/LQNYrv), the first 'vis' child rect's width is approx 31% of the chart's width.

Comment: it's not that simple.. your script comments out MBostock's original tree layout, and does different things feeding the data in a different manner. you can check out the original at https://codepen.io/aug2uag/pen/VQjzQL?editors=0010

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've already been comparing to Mike's original v3 code all along. The point is that Mike's d3v3 treemap code is not compatible with d3v4. As mentioned above, I ending figuring the cause of the overlapping child rects myself, which was due to an incorrect port from the v3 coordinate model (x/dx,y,dy) to the v4 coordinate model (x0/x1/y0/y1). There's still a difference in the layout algorithm, but that's not a bug, so I'm going to close this question as self-answered. But thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up figuring this out myself. The incorrectly positioned child rects were due to an incorrect port from the v3 layout coordinate model (x/dx,y/dy) to the v4 layout coordinate model (x0/x1,y0/y1).

Examples...

1) In function rect(), the width/height calculations from the original v3 sample:
    x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x)
    y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y)

Were ported to v4 like this:
    x(d.x0 + d.x1) - x(d.x0)
    y(d.y0 + d.y1) - y(d.y0)

My v4 fixes:
    x(d.x1) - x(d.x0)
    y(d.y1) - y(d.y0)

2) In function layout(), the width value from the original v3 sample:
    dx

Was ported to v4 as this:
    d.x1

My v4 fix:
    d.x1 - d.x0

The working code is in my pen. See the second paragraph, near the top of my original question, for the pen link.

[Pic of fixed D3V4 Zoomable Treemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HmHV.png)